# Using non-trivial picture as node in diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to use some picture as nodes in diagram. I think the `forest` package is best for diagrams. but I can't use characters in tikz-picture as node of tree here.

see comments below: `\fineMatrix{b}` drawed with empty cells (with filling but without characters).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\fineMatrix}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (2, 2);
    \shade[top color=yellow, bottom color=gray] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
    \shade[top color=gray, bottom color=yellow] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \node[anchor=center] at (0.5, 0.5) {  $#1_{21}$  };
    \node[anchor=center] at (1.5, 1.5) {  $#1_{12}$  };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    %simple tree - fine
    \begin{forest}
        for tree=
        [A [
           B
        ]]
    \end{forest}

%some picture - fine also
\fineMatrix{c}

%tree with picture - charaters was lost :(
    \begin{forest}
        for tree=
        [A [
        {\fineMatrix{b}}
        ]]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` environments isn't supported. `forest` is a `tikzpicture` environment. Hence, you can't expect this to work :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting `tikzpicture`s is not supported. `forest` is a `tikzpicture`. Hence, you cannot expect this to work, unfortunately.

How about something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\forestset{%
  fine Matrix/.style={
    minimum height = 2cm,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    tikz+={
      \draw (.north) coordinate (t) ++(-1,-2) coordinate (bl) rectangle ++(2,2) coordinate (tr);
      \shade [top color=yellow, bottom color=gray, draw] ($(bl)!.5!(bl |- tr)$) coordinate (l) rectangle (t);
      \shade [top color=gray, bottom color=yellow, draw] (bl -| t) rectangle (l -| tr) coordinate (r);
      \node [anchor=center] at ($(bl)!.5!(l -| t)$) {$#1_{21}$};
      \node [anchor=center] at ($(l -| t)!.5!(tr)$) {$#1_{12}$};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A
    [, fine Matrix=b
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: checkered node in tree]

Note that

```
for tree=
```

and then immediately starting the tree specification isn't doing anything and may be problematic, as it expects an argument. Either delete or say `for tree={}` if, for some reason, you want to retain it for posterity.

Comment: It is fine, thanks. And also thanks for note about `for tree`

Comment: @cfr +1 for your excellent work.

Comment: BTW, how I can use 2 or more parameters, not only `b` in this example?

Comment: @AdelChepkunov `fine Matrix/.style n args=7{<definition using 7 arguments>}`.

Comment: Obviously use `2` rather than `7` if you only want `2`. Anything up to `9` is OK, although I can't say I've ever tested that many!

Comment: And I also added two rows for define size into your example, childnodes was positioned incorrectly without ones. I hope it will be useful for other readers.

Comment: @AdelChepkunov Thanks. I meant to do that, actually, but I forgot.